# XQuery multiple namespace declaration

Tags: xml, xquery, transformation, xmlbeans

During my research I think the problem is the [fn-bea:serialize()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13171_01/alsb/docs25/userguide/appendixxquery.html#wp1047384) function.

The XQuery engine I'm using `org.apache.xmlbeans` writes the namespace for *every* `child node`, while the OSB Transformation just writes for the `root node`.

Here is the transformation result snippet from OSB where the `serialize()` function is called:

```
    <urn:XML>
&lt;tns:telegramm TITLE="Universelle Messtelegramme" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="tns">
                    &lt;tns:header ANGELEGT_AM="20160705" ANGELEGT_UM="221626" ANGELEGT_VON="ub2" ANZAHL_RS="12" AUFARB="" DATEINAME="CW4122Y20160705221626" FHM="K000003508191" GANGRICHTUNG="V" GERAET="CW4" IDENT_ART="F" MATERIALNUMMER="" MESSDATUM="20160705" MESSZEIT="221626" PARKNR="" SERIALNUMMER="" TAG_FAHRZEUG="" TAG_RADSATZ="" TPLNR="94800442311-7" URMASS="" WERK="122Y"/>
                    &lt;tns:position EINBAUORT="01" LFDNR="1">
                            &lt;tns:komponente TYP="Radscheibe links">
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="28,6" SORTFELD="SH"/>
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="29,9" SORTFELD="SD"/>
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="10,5" SORTFELD="QR"/>
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="136,8" SORTFELD="BR"/>
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="0,0" SORTFELD="HHY"/>
                            &lt;/tns:komponente>
                            &lt;tns:komponente TYP="Radscheibe rechts">
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="28,8" SORTFELD="SH"/>
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="30,0" SORTFELD="SD"/>
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="11,0" SORTFELD="QR"/>
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="136,5" SORTFELD="BR"/>
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="0,0" SORTFELD="HHY"/>
                            &lt;/tns:komponente>
                            &lt;tns:komponente TYP="Radsatz">
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="1361,2" SORTFELD="AR"/>
                            &lt;/tns:komponente>
                            &lt;tns:komponente TYP="Radsatz">
                                    &lt;tns:merkmal MESSWERT="1421,2" SORTFELD="SR"/>
                            &lt;/tns:komponente>
                    &lt;/tns:position>
            &lt;/tns:telegramm>
</urn:XML>
```

however the `XmlBeans` Transformation writes the `soapenv` and `tns` for every childnode like this:

```
  <urn:XML>&lt;tns:telegramm TITLE="Universelle Messtelegramme" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="tns">
            &lt;tns:header ANGELEGT_AM="20160705" ANGELEGT_UM="221626" ANGELEGT_VON="ub2" ANZAHL_RS="12" AUFARB="" DATEINAME="CW4122Y20160705221626" FHM="K000003508191" GANGRICHTUNG="V" GERAET="CW4" IDENT_ART="F" MATERIALNUMMER="" MESSDATUM="20160705" MESSZEIT="221626" PARKNR="" SERIALNUMMER="" TAG_FAHRZEUG="" TAG_RADSATZ="" TPLNR="94800442311-7" URMASS="" WERK="122Y" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="tns"/>
            &lt;tns:position EINBAUORT="01" LFDNR="1" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="tns">
...
```

Searching the web and reading the [apache documentation](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setUseDefaultNamespace()) I couldn't find any information on this scenario, to delete the namespaces from the child nodes when already declared on the root.

Comment: Either way is valid XML that is equivalent. Are you worried about the size of the payload or aesthetics?

Comment: My assertion fails due to that. I use [custommonkey xmlunit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/package-summary.html) for the assertion

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the XmlOptions [`setAggressiveNamespaces()`](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setSaveAggressiveNamespaces())

> Causes the saver to reduce the number of namespace prefix declarations. The saver will do this by passing over the document twice, first to collect the set of needed namespace declarations, and then second to actually save the document with the declarations collected at the root.

and/or [`setSaveSuggestedPrefixes()`](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setSaveImplicitNamespaces(java.util.Map)) with a hashmap of the namespaces?

> If namespaces have already been declared outside the scope of the fragment being saved, this allows those mappings to be passed down to the saver, so the prefixes are not re-declared.

```
HashMap NamespaceMap = new HashMap();
NamespaceMap.put("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soapenv");
NamespaceMap.put("tns", "tns");

XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();
xmlOptions.setSavePrettyPrint();
xmlOptions.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(NamespaceMap);
xmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces();
xmlOptions.setUseDefaultNamespace();

try {
    docObject.save(xmlFile, xmlOptions);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried both. The problem or my assumption is, that the engine doesn't adopt these namespaces because it's transformed to `string` see [fn-bea:serialize](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13171_01/alsb/docs25/userguide/appendixxquery.html#wp1047384)